# Trimming road end at the intersection?

Tags: qgis, intersection

I have a road centerline that I have used to create buffers that represent road area. Now I need to fix the intersections. As you can see on the picture, if the road end is touching the non-end of the other road, I need to trim it's road area. If road end is touching another road end, I should trim the smaller one (shorter one).

[image]

Any way to do this, preferably in QGIS?

EDIT:

- Road areas that belong to the different centerlines must not be
  merged.
- All roads in this case have the same classification.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient if you just merged all the road buffers?

Comment: @Erik Yes it would, but for this project I am not allowed to do that. For some reason road areas that belong to the different centerlines must not be merged.

Comment: You could buffer the roads by classification. Highways, primary roads, secondary roads, etc. Then clip the primary roads with the highways, then the secondary with both highways and primary, etc, pp. Also, you should look into how to achieve rectangular line caps instead of round ones.

Comment: Already done that :) I stumbled upon this situation where the roads have the same classification.

Comment: @ZoranPetrović can you [edit] to clarify: when you say "trim the smaller one" do you mean trim the buffer that belongs to a road/segment that's shorter in length, or of a lower classification, or something else?

Comment: Yes, shorter in length. I edited the question.

Comment: `Union` will break the polygons into overlapping and non-overlapping portions. Then perhaps one of the [solutions for handling sliver polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=sliver+polygon+%5Bqgis%5D) will help you handle the overlapping portions.

Comment: Another possible method is to first dissolve the buffers, then try to split them back out. Perhaps by selecting the longest roads and using them for splits.

Answer (score 1):

If one large buffer is acceptable, you can [dissolve the boundaries](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html) of your buffers.

In **Vector/ Geoprocessing/ Buffer**, choose **Dissolve result**.

[image: buffer dialog screenshot]

Sample output:

[image: sample output map screenshot]

Comment: I am not allowed to do that. Road areas that belong to the different centerlines must not be merged.

Comment: If you don't mind the PostGIS tool, then 1)https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300684/how-get-intersection-of-polygons-in-the-same-table-by-postgis thus, you will get fragments from the intersection of buffers; 2) remove the fragments.