# How get list of id's of intersecting of polygons in the same table by PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, intersection, st-intersects

I have a table looking this this

```
id     geom
1      POLYON....
2      POLYON....
3      POLYON....
4      POLYON....
5      POLYON....
6      POLYON....
....
300    POLYON....
```

Some (not all) of them are intersecting, some don't. What I need is a new column, with the id's of the polygons that are intersecting: Polygon with `id` 4 intersects polygons with `id` 4, 76, 298, 55.

```
id     geom           intersects
1      POLYON....     4, 55, 8, 1
2      POLYON....     none
3      POLYON....     99, 1, 298, 65, 88, 253, 76
4      POLYON....     4, 76, 298, 55
5      POLYON....     189
6      POLYON....     none
....   ...            ...
300    POLYON....     99
```

The column `intersects` can be of type `array` or of type `string`, with a separator like comma, semicolon, ... I think a good start is [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300684/how-get-intersection-of-polygons-in-the-same-table-by-postgis) (Making sure to avoid comparing the a polygon to itself. Also avoid comparing a pair of polygon twice)

```
SELECT a.id
FROM mytable a, mytable b
WHERE a.ID < b.ID
AND ST_INTERSECTS(a.geom, b.geom);
```

But I am not sure how to go on from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html):

```sql
select
a.id,
a.name,
array_to_string(array_agg(b.id),';') as intersecting_ids -- use array_agg() to get a list of the ids and array_to_string() to make it a string if you want
from myschema.mytable as a

left join -- use a left join to also get the elements from a that do not intersect with b
myschema.mytable as b
on ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom)

where 
a.id != b.id -- dont do a self-join

group by -- array_agg() is an aggregate function so you need to use group by
a.id,
a.name
```

---

You can do an update for example like this:

```sql
alter table myschema.mytable 
add column intersecting_ids_array integer ARRAY, 
add column intersecting_ids_string varchar
```

```sql
with subquery as (
select
a.id,
a.name,
array_agg(b.id) as intersecting_ids_array,
array_to_string(array_agg(b.id),';') as intersecting_ids_string
from myschema.mytable as a

left join
myschema.mytable as b
on ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom)

where 
a.id != b.id

group by
a.id,
a.name
)
update myschema.mytable
set intersecting_ids_array = subquery.intersecting_ids_array,
intersecting_ids_string = subquery.intersecting_ids_string
from subquery
where mytable.id = subquery.id
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is more complicated than I thought. Thanks a lot. Is there an easy way to combine that with an `UPDATE`? Let's say I have a column `intersection_geoms` and I want to write the results into this column... I mean, one could perform a `JOIN`, but is there a way to combine this with an `UPDATE`

Comment: Thansk a lot..!

Answer (score 2):

Simpler:

```
UPDATE
  <table> AS a
  SET (
    intersecting_ids_array,
    intersecting_ids_count
  ) = (
    SELECT
      ARRAY_AGG(b.id),
      COUNT(b.id)
    FROM
      <table>
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
      AND
      a.id <> b.id
  )
;
```